# css styling issue with header close button

Tags: html, css

I have following `div` opening up on click of image to show zoomed version on image.
It doing what it is supposed to by using `jquery show(), and hide(),`
but i m not getting how to style it, I'm using following code:

```
<div id="mainImage">
  ;;;
</div>
<div id="zoomPdpImage" style="display:none;z-index:2000;background-color:silver;">
<div id="closeZoomImgButton">
<span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-dialog-form">&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" class="close" role="button">
        <span>close</span>          
    </a>
</div>
<img src="http://localhost:/..." alt="${imageAlt}" title="image"/>
</div>
```

and *styling* for that:

```
#closeZoomImgButton 
{
 width: auto;
 height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 background: #000 url("../images/Close_X_Icon.png") no-repeat 570px 10px;
}
#closeZoomImgButton .close 
{
  border:0 none;
  border-radius:0 0 0 0;
  height:32px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  width:32px;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}
#closeZoomImgButton .close span{margin:0;padding:0;}
#closeZoomImgButton .close:hover, #closeZoomImgButton .close:focus { padding:0; }
```

so I am able to click and close zoomed image but entire header is now clickable i want only close button to be clickable and should have on focus and hover effect to know that it is click-able.

Any suggestions plz.

Comment: Can you maybe put this in a jsfiddle.net

Comment: i m trying to make fiddle but i think im not able to put any close button image there

Comment: You can upload it to a server and just link it in the css..

Comment: ya that how we ideally do,but its on local machine apache, following is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WFyMu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what the issue is, you didn't add the id to the span for closing.

Please see updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WFyMu/5/

I changed this:

```
<span>close</span>
```

To this:

```
<span id="closeZoomImgButton">close</span>
```

Now when you click the close span it will hide. But I don't know if this is what you wanted?

Comment: hi thanks for quick reply, whatever you are saying is correct thats what i want but,if you see in updated fiddle,if we remove id="closeZoomImgButton" from div tag and put it on span it is breaking image,and if we have it on div tag entire div is clickable,you getting where im stuck:(

Comment: i want it like you can click anywhere on the image and only if you click on close button then close it,,,

Comment: The reason is because the background image for the div is really big and you can't see the close span. I don't know why the image is so big? Does it need to be that big: 570px by 10px?

Comment: ooh thats my bad im newbie to css,iwanted to align close button to right hand side

Comment: Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/WFyMu/7/ I downsized the background image and it's working, you can see the close span, when you click it, it will close. But the background image is smaller now. I don't know if it needs to be 570px by 10px?

Comment: sorry for replying late, and yes it is correct, but since i want something different, can you tell me how can i have just a header with black color and a close button at top right corner and clicking on that button only it should close,i dont want any text with that like "close" or something

Comment: i think it is close upto my solution,but still i m worried about that close button, i want only button no text

Comment: oh thanks i got it great, simple but sometimes we do it worse way ,exactly what i want , thanks dude..:)),i would upvote your ans

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and tell

```
     #closeZoomImgButton 
     {
      background: url("../images/Close_X_Icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 30px;
      left: 440px;
      position: absolute;
      top: -18px;
      width: 30px;
      z-index: 90003;
      }
```

position, z-index and width is important

Comment: i tried it but is having same effect :( i have fiddle at jsfiddle.net/WFyMu/2